# mongo find where var is found in array field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have mongo data that looks like:

```
{
    "name": "test1",
    "source": ["source1"]
},
{ 
    "name": "test2",
    "source": ["source1", "source2"]
}
```

I need to do a find for a document where "source1" is in the source array.
I've tried to get $elemMatch to work as:

db.myCollection.find({source: {$elemMatch: {$eq:['source1']}}})
also tried
db.myCollection.find({source: {$elemMatch: {$eq:{source: "source1"}}}})

Neither return any documents.

I must be using the $elemMatch wrong, or else it may be the wrong thing to use.
How can I do a find where an array field in a document contains a specific element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below syntax when you want to search for **simple** elements and **not** sub-documents.

```
db.mycollection.find({"source":"source1"}})
```

This works because the elements in the array are not documents, but literals. The query condition is applied on each literal. If a matching literal is found, that particular document is returned.

If you do want to use [***$elemMatch***](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/), which is not necessary here, the syntax would be:

```
db.mycollection.find({"source":{$elemMatch:{$eq:"source1"}}})
```

The query that you tried:

```
db.myCollection.find({source: {$elemMatch: {$eq:{source: "source1"}}}})
```

would work if the source array were to have sub documents in them, such as:

```
{ 
    "name": "test2",
    "source": [{"source":"source1"}]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `$elemMatch` here. If your field is an array (`source: [1, ..., 4]`) and all you need is to find whether one element exist there, all you need is a simple find.

```
db.mycollection.find({source: 'source1'}})
```

Also note that you can put an index on the field `source` and it will work just fine.